# what is the actual type of argument for a DriverManager.registerDriver( ) method?

Tags: java, jdbc, driver

Is it a driver object of the driver class JdbcOdbcDriver? if yes then what is its argument signature? and if its an object of the driver class then why do we need to write the argument in this way : `(new sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc Driver());`

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Obtaining a jdbc connection using jdbc-odbc bridge.

Answer (score 1):

As an end user you normally do not need to do anything with the `DriverManager.RegisterDriver()` method. It is used by the `Driver`-implementation itself to register itself when its class is loaded.

There are some exceptions to this rule (drivers which don't self-register), but these don't usually occur (if at all) and if they do you would specifically know you would need to use this method yourself.

For a JDBC 4.0-compliant driver in Java 6 or higher you do not need to do anything: the driver will be loaded and registered automatically.

For a JDBC 3.0 or earlier driver, or in Java 5 or earlier you only need to load the class using

```
Class.forName("<FQN of driver class>");
```

If this is done the driver will register itself with the DriverManager.

Comment: Regards Mark, i appreciate your response in this context that the drivers nowadays get registered itself and also that we have an alternate method ( Class.forname() ) but my question still remains the same , i know the functionality of the above said method but what pricks me is the argument type.If i reframe my question it will be "is sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc Driver" the class for which we are creting an object of and passing it to the DriverManager.RegisterDriver() method?

Comment: The object is any object instantiated from a class derived from `java.sql.Driver` (so any JDBC Driver). `JdbcOdbcDriver` is just one such implementation (and one you should usually avoid if there is a specific implementation of `java.sql.Driver` for your database)